# Solidworks PDM API in Python--getting AttributeError object has no attribute 'QueryInterface'

Tags: python, api, com, solidworks, comtypes

I've written a bunch of Python code for tagging our vendor files in Solidworks PDM and I'm trying to use the Solidworks PDM API to actually apply that information. Officially the API only supports C# and VB, but I'd like to keep everything in Python if possible, because everything else is already in Python (and it's the language I'm most comfortable programming with). Here's a high level list of what I'm trying to accomplish:

1. Check out a bunch of files
2. Update a data card variable
3. Check those files back in

The API defines two ways main ways to check in/check out/update variables in individual files--one for individual files and one for groups of files. You can use methods accessible through the IEdmVault5 interface to perform all 3 operations on individual files, and to perform these operations on groups of files you have to use 3 separate interfaces--IEdmBatchGet (checkout), IEdmBatchUpdate2 (update variables), and  IEdmBatchUnlock (check in).

I was able write functional code that does all 3 things for each individual file, but it was slow when operating on many files--my goal is to update a couple thousand files at once. Getting the batch interfaces to work proved much trickier, but I was able to eventually get batch checkout and checkin working (and it was definitely worth it--each operation was about 10X faster using the vault interface). However, I'm gotten pretty stuck trying to make variable updating work. Here's my code for updating variables:

```
import win32com.client
import os

import comtypes.client as cc
cc.GetModule('C:\Program Files (x86)\SOLIDWORKS PDM\EdmInterface.dll')
import comtypes.gen._5FA2C692_8393_4F31_9BDB_05E6F807D0D3_0_5_22 as pdm_lib2

vault_name = 'vault_name'
folder_path = 'some_folder_path'

def connect_to_vault(vault_name, lib = 'comtypes'):
    if lib == 'comtypes':
        vault = cc.CreateObject('ConisioLib.EdmVault.1')
        vault.LoginAuto(vault_name, 0)

    else: 
        vault = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch('ConisioLib.EdmVault.1')
        vault.LoginAuto(vault_name, 0)

    return vault

def getrefs(vault, filenames, folder_path):
    DocIDs = []
    ProjIDs = []

    for filename in filenames:
        temp_ProjID = vault.GetFolderFromPath(folder_path)
        temp_DocID = vault.GetFileFromPath(filename, temp_ProjID)[0] #this fails when I use a comtypes generated vault

        DocIDs.append(temp_DocID.ID)
        ProjIDs.append(temp_ProjID.ID)

    print('Document and Project IDs pulled')

    return DocIDs, ProjIDs

vault = connect_to_vault(vault_name)
ref_vault =connect_to_vault(vault_name, lib = 'win32com') 

filenames = [folder_path + s for s in os.listdir(folder_path)]
DocIDs, ProjIDs = getrefs(ref_vault, filenames, folder_path)

#Using Comtypes to update files
VarIDs = [54] * len(DocIDs) #Updating description only
var_values = [['foo' + str(s)] for s in range(len(DocIDs))] #dummy values for now

update_vars = vault.CreateUtility(2) #create instance of BatchUpdate 

for i, file in enumerate(DocIDs): 
    update_vars.SetVar(file, VarIDs[i], var_values[i], '', 1)

pdm_error = [pdm_lib2.EdmBatchError2()] * len(DocIDs)
update_vars.CommitUpdate([pdm_error])
```

When I call update_vars.CommitUpdate([pdm_error]), I get the following error:

```
ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'AttributeError'>: 'list' object has no attribute 'QueryInterface'
```

I'm not sure why this method is expecting an object with a 'QueryInterface' attribute--I'm only passing it a list of structs, not a full COM object like my file vault. I also tried using win32com to execute the method:

```
update_vars = ref_vault.CreateUtility(2) #create instance of BatchUpdate, use win32com instead

for i, file in enumerate(DocIDs): 
    update_vars.SetVar(file, VarIDs[i], var_values[i], '', 1)

pdm_error = [pdm_lib2.EdmBatchError2()] * len(DocIDs)
update_vars.CommitUpdate([pdm_error])
```

And now I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-222-0c49fb0861b9>", line 7, in <module>
    update_vars.CommitUpdate([pdm_error])

  File "D:\Users\apreacher\Documents\Shared Files\Python\Webscraping_projects\Helper Modules\pdm_lib.py", line 1500, in CommitUpdate
    , poCallback)

  File "C:\Users\apreacher\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 467, in _ApplyTypes_
    self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(dispid, 0, wFlags, retType, argTypes, *args),

MemoryError: CreatingSafeArray
```

And this is where I'm stuck. I haven't been able to make any headway on getting the CommitUpdate method to work properly. I also have the method definitions from the files generated by makepy.py and comtypes, but I don't really know how to interpret them:

makepy.py method definition:

```
def CommitUpdate(self, ppoRetErrors=pythoncom.Missing, poCallback=0):
    'method Commit'
    return self._ApplyTypes_(3, 1, (3, 0), ((24612, 2), (9, 49)), 'CommitUpdate', None,ppoRetErrors
        , poCallback)
```

comtypes generated file:

```
COMMETHOD([dispid(3), helpstring('method Commit')], HRESULT, 'CommitUpdate',
          ( ['out'], POINTER(_midlSAFEARRAY(EdmBatchError2)), 'ppoRetErrors' ),
          ( ['in', 'optional'], POINTER(IEdmCallback), 'poCallback', 0 ),
          ( ['out', 'retval'], POINTER(c_int), 'plErrorCount' )),
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What version of PDM are you using?  (I am on Pro 2019 sp4.)

I just noticed an inconsistency in your code.  `vault.CreateUtility(2)` would (in .NET) return an object of type `IEdmBatchUpdate`.  4 lines later, you are calling the method `CommitUpdate` which only exists for the newer API `IEdmBatchUpdate2`  (see [https://help.solidworks.com/2020/english/api/epdmapi/EPDM.Interop.epdm~EPDM.Interop.epdm.IEdmBatchUpdate2.html](https://help.solidworks.com/2020/english/api/epdmapi/EPDM.Interop.epdm%7EEPDM.Interop.epdm.IEdmBatchUpdate2.html) ).

I can tell you for certain under C#, this would require casting the result of `CreatUtility` to the proper object type.

It seems you are looking for a way to automate entry of data into file datacards.
Have you tried using data import rules?  https://help.solidworks.com/2020/English/EnterprisePDM/Admin/c_Working_With_Variable_Values_overview.htm

Comment: Could you elaborate? What would that practically mean for this particular question?