# Solidworks PDM API in Python

Tags: python, api, solidworks

I'm attempting to perform basic functions with the SW PDM API using Python, but running into some problems. I'm able to log in and get a file handle, but when I try to get an EnumVar, I get "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetEnumeratorVariable'".  I've done this in VB.NET but Python's pretty new to me.

Here's my (very basic) code:

```
import win32com.client

vault_name = 'PDM Test'
folder_path = 'C:\\PDM Test\\Production Records\\MF.00000 - MF.00499'
file_name = "MF.00576.pdf"
full_file_path = folder_path + "\\" + file_name

vault = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch('ConisioLib.EdmVault.1')
vault.LoginAuto(vault_name, 0)

varvalue = ""

aFile = vault.GetFileFromPath(full_file_path , None)[0]
vars = aFile.GetEnumeratorVariable(file_name)    <==== error here
vars.GetVar("ItemNumber", "", varvalue)

print(varvalue)
```

I think the issue may be using a standard python variable to hold an IEDMFile5 object... in VB.NET, the variable is declared thus:

```
Dim aFile as IEDMFile5
```

But I can't directly declare a type in Python, so I'm kinda stuck.  I've spent a couple of hours searching and trying stuff suggested by ChatGPT, but it's no smarter than I am on this.  A few quick pointers on how to handle this situation would be greatly appreciated.  Ultimately, I just need to get a file, check it out, change a variable and check it back in. I found this post where the OP says he got this to work with individual files, but sadly he didn't post the code for that: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60582778/solidworks-pdm-api-in-python-getting-attributeerror-object-has-no-attribute-qu?noredirect=1&lq=1)